# HTML table - best way to hide row and move subsequent controls into its place?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Here's the scenario: In a table, there are rows and columns of labels and controls.  There are some scenarios in the aspx.cs that we can say based on "x" condition, the label and control are hidden.

For example: This is done using simple  (e.g. 4  rows> and .

```
 Label 1  Control1       Label 2  Control2       Label 3  Control3    

 Label 4  Control4       Label 5  Control5       Label 6  Control6    

 Label 7  Control7       Label 8  Control8       Label 9  Control9    

 Label 10 Control10      Label 11 Control1       Label 12 Control2
```

If the code behind says hide Label 8 and Control 8, then this is what it currently looks like:

```
 Label 1  Control1       Label 2  Control2       Label 3  Control3    

 Label 4  Control4       Label 5  Control5       Label 6  Control6    

 Label 7  Control7                               Label 9  Control9    

 Label 10 Control10      Label 11 Control1       Label 12 Control2
```

That doesn't look very good.  One would expect that Label & control 11 would move into the position where Label & control 8 was.
I was thinking the quick and dirty way of doing this was to do something like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <table>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
           </table>  
       <td>
       <td>
           <table>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
           </table>  
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Then that way I would hide the "tr" of the control and it would move the rows up.
But I'm thinking that there has to be a better way but not entirely sure.
Any advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: td's are a part of row. And as my understanding there is a relation between td's of a row. If you want to move td then you will have to use jquery or java-script for that. Because css will not move the td it will just hide the td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tables for layout purposes has all but been replaced with DIVs and CSS.  Unless you're specifically outputting tabular data, its never a good idea to rely on tables for layout.

In your description, it sounds like you're trying to get the rows to shuffle up rather than everything to shift to the left.  In your example, 11 takes 8's spot.  You could also make 9 take 8, 10 wrap up to 9, and 11 & 12 shift left using DIVs and CSS.

Check out this very ugly DIV/CSS example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXdbm/) or the code below.  Here I'm hiding 5, and 8 shifts up.

```
<div style="float:left;margin:10px">
    <div>
        1
    </div>
    <div>
        4
    </div>
    <div>
        7
    </div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin:10px">
    <div>
        2
    </div>
    <div style="display:none">
        5
    </div>
    <div>
        8
    </div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin:10px">
    <div>
        3
    </div>
    <div>
        6
    </div>
    <div>
        9
    </div>
</div>
```

​

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for Jeremy.  So what I believe I can do is give the div's an ID.  In the code behind after the logic tells me what I need to hide, i can just set the div style to "display:none" in the code behind right? And that would take care of the rest. i think that's the way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Yep that strategy should work fine.  You can also do it client side of course with jQuery or JavaScript easy enough using the same strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Table cells don't float into place - they are fixed width based on the other row's cell content so tables won't serve you for this feature unless you change what gets rendered into each of the cells at server render time (ie. your code shifts the elements).

If you have a fixed number of columns you can use  elements with a float:left style. You probably will have to use fixed widths and hide overflow to keep the element from stretching:

```
<style>
#GridContainer
{
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden            
}
.row {
    clear: both;
}
.row>div
{
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;   
}
</style>

<div id="GridContainer">

 <div class="row">
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
 </div>      

 <div class="row">
   <div>item 4</div>
   <div>item 5</div>
   <div>item 6</div>
   <div>item 7</div>       
  </div>  

 <div class="row">
   <div>item 8</div>
   <div>item 9</div>
   <div>item 10</div>
   <div>item 11</div>       
   <div>item 12</div>       
   <div>item 13</div>       
 </div>
</div>
```

You can play with the jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6tYnN/3/

With this set up you can simply remove elements and they will automatically 'close up the gap'.